# How can I identify bluetooth connected nodes when using MessageAPI in Android Wear?

Tags: android, bluetooth, wear-os, android-bluetooth

I'm trying to build a Wear app that broadcasts messages to my phone. What I'm trying to achieve is that the messages are sent ONLY when the phone (the Node) is connected via bluetooth. Is there any way to accomplish this? I know there's `node.isNearby()`, however this method returns true only when other nodes are nearby geographically.

Comment: I have to use capabilityapi

Answer (score 0):

Here's hoping that we're on the same page, but [`BluetoothProfile.ServiceListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothProfile.ServiceListener.html) might just help.

If [`onServiceConnected`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothProfile.ServiceListener.html#onServiceConnected(int,android.bluetooth.BluetoothProfile)), then proceed with [sending a message](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/messages.html#SendMessage).